# image is zooming in inside woocommerce product image container (CSS)

Tags: css, wordpress, woocommerce

I am working on an online store using WordPress and woocommerce plugin. I had an issue with resizing the images. So I decided to force the images inside the shop page using additional CSS to show as following:

```
.products ul li.product .btWooShopLoopItemInner .bt_bb_image img, ul.products li.product .btWooShopLoopItemInner 
.bt_bb_image img{
  display: block;
  max-width:250px;
  max-height:250px;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
    
}
```

It worked fine for forcing images to show with my specified width and height, but the issue now is if I place any image bigger than the height and width above, it shows as a zoomed-in picture it doesn't show fully.

I tried to zoom out the picture using scaling but it reduced the whole container's size. Any idea of showing the picture fully without getting automatically zoomed in, and without resizing the original picture?

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer. WooCommerce automatically crops the image (instead of zooming into it). In order to disable the cropping image option:

- Go to *Appearance* > *WooCommerce*.
- Click on *Product images*.
- Choose *Uncropped*.

The image will fully appear inside the product container with the specified dimensions, assuming you specify any using CSS.

Comment: Life saver, worked like a charm, thanks!